# iOS AKMIDISampler no audio output

Tags: ios, avfoundation, audiokit

I'm using the AKMIDISampler with a soundfont, on iOS (11.3), but I can't get audio output.
The setup, for now, is minimal:

```
    midiSampler = AKMIDISampler()
    samplerVolume = AKBooster(midiSampler)
    mixer.connect(input: samplerVolume)

    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
    let soundPath = ("\(bundlePath)/Sounds/GigaPiano")
    do { _ = try self.midiSampler.loadSoundFont(soundPath, preset: 0, bank: 0) }
    catch { print("Error loading soundfont") }

    mixer.start()
    AudioKit.output = mixer
    do {
        _ = try AudioKit.engine.start()
    } catch {
        print("AudioKit wouldn't start!")
    }
    midiSampler.enableMIDI()
```

Setting a breakpoint in AKMIDISampler.handleMIDI() indicates that MIDI data is getting there, so it seems like it must be an audio issue. No errors loading the soundfont. Also, I added the AKBooster out of desperation, simply because it appeared in an example app; it's the same without it.

Any tips on how I might debug this?

**UPDATE:**

As outlined in the comments, I do have audio, but **very** quiet, distorted, and **not** through the main iPhone speaker—only the earpiece. My current, **minimal** code (with some defensiveness around soundfont loading) is:

```
    midiSampler = AKMIDISampler()
    mixer = AKMixer(midiSampler)
    let bundlePath = Bundle.main.bundlePath
    let soundPath = ("\(bundlePath)/Sounds/KorgTritonPiano")
    do { _ = try self.midiSampler.loadSoundFont(soundPath, preset: 0, bank: 0) }
    catch {
        print("Failed in loadSoundFont. Try loadMelodicSoundFont...")
        do { _ = try self.midiSampler.loadMelodicSoundFont(soundPath, preset: 0) }
        catch { print("Error loading soundfont") }
    }
    AudioKit.output = mixer
    do { try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .mixWithOthers) }
    catch { print("Can't update session info...") }
    do {
        _ = try AudioKit.start()
    } catch {
        print("AudioKit wouldn't start!")
    }
    midiSampler.enableMIDI()
```

As also mentioned in the comments, a minimal AKOscillator, with an AKEnvelope connected directly to AudioKit.output does produce sound from the speaker. So it's something with the AKMIDISampler or AKSampler(?). I notice that *this issue has come up in the past* and been closed, but perhaps iOS 11.3 is breaking something anew?

Since the GitHub page asks us to confirm issues here, I'm really hoping somebody from AudioKit can respond (so I can avoid posting to GitHub). I've been up and down the class hierarchy, trying to figure out where it might be failing, but I'm coming up with nothing.

In case it helps, I'm on iOS 11.3 (beta 15E5201e), Xcode 9.3 beta 4, macOS 10.13.4 beta 4. Since the 11.3 and 10.13.4 seem to be released now, I'll update later tonight. If the iOS or Xcode version is a know issue, I assume that would turn up on GitHub, but nothing is documented.

**UPDATE 2:** Updated Xcode, iOS, macOS to latest release version with no change.

**UPDATE 3:** Logging the device with `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().currentRoute.outputs`, from *within* `AKMIDIPlayer.handleMIDI()`, indicates that the speaker is selected. I'm totally stumped. Could this be Apple's bug?

**UPDATE 4:** Deliberately setting the output to `PlayAndRecord` (i.e., `<Device: Receiver (Built-In Receiver)>`) outputs nothing, and setting it to speaker outputs to the receiver. Maybe my dev phone suffered a stroke... **SubUpdate:** Nope, verified same behaviour on another iPhone. I'm done. Will see if I can get anywhere pulling AK out of my project and building a sampler from straight AVFoundation. Not much different, from what I've seen. At least then I'll know for sure if AK is even involved.

**UPDATE 5:** Coded up a fully non-AudioKit version, based on AVAudioUnitSampler. Same problem. Also same strangeness of `session.currentRoute` reporting that it's playing to the speaker (which it's not). Is it possible that something in the Xcode project could be causing this? If anyone has any thoughts or ideas, any and all help would still be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I remember having an issue getting my soundfont to load a while back. But I eventually  got it to work using the loadMelodicSoundFont(_:preset:) call.  For the record, I added my sf2 file directly to the project and used the sf2 filename (minus the extension), not the file path.  Maybe give that a try.

Comment: Interesting, @c_booth. I'll give melodic soundfont a try. Thanks. Out of curiosity, were you also able to load the original sf2 (i.e., the one that didn't work) without errors?

Comment: Okay, some progress. I have sound, but it's from the earpiece, not the speaker (iPhone). I tried `AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true`, but same thing.

Comment: That's a totally unrelated problem - so definitely progress!  Have you set the session category?  see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47684764/akaudioplayer-no-sound-in-speakers-only-with-headphones/47695714#47695714

Comment: Well, no luck, sadly. I've tried a bunch of variations on setting the session, but none of them changes anything. Output is from the earpiece, very quietly, and distorted. (Judging by google, I'm not the first to have this problem!)

Answer (score 0):

The new AKSampler in AudioKit 4.2 solved my problem! Perhaps not exactly an "answer", but definitely a solution, definitely a "sampler", and definitely in AudioKit. So hopefully helpful for others.

Comment: I thought I should mention here that completely rebuilding my project, in a new Xcode workspace, cured the above problems with AKSampler (now AKAppleSampler) and AKMIDISampler. Strange but true.