# Audiokit: No output in loudspeaker (iPhone 4s) just in ear-speaker. AKSettings with .defaultToSpeaker does not work

Tags: ios, audiokit

I figured out some of the iOS AudioKit examples (for example the Recorder-app) on a iPhone 4s but I have always the problem that there is no sound from the loudspeaker, just from the ear-speaker. I made a simple record and play-app with AudioKit but I could not fix it:

```
try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .defaultToSpeaker)
```

does not do its work, why? I tried out other solutions which I found on different mailing lists like

```
AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
```

or

```
try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
```

nothing helped. I use Xcode 11 with Swift 5 for my own coding and the current AudioKit-release.
Thanks for sharing your ideas...
(with my libpd apps the speaker worked always fine which means it is not a  hardware problem)

Comment: Have you tried toggling the silent mode switch? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47695714/2717159

Answer (score -1):

It might have to do with the order of setting it up. 
I've tried it with this piece of code and it works for me:

```
    do {
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(.playAndRecord, options: .defaultToSpeaker)
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, options: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
        try AudioKit.start()
        try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(AVAudioSession.PortOverride.speaker)
    } catch {
        AKLog("Could not set up session: error: \(error)")
    }
```